# Why is invalid_dict = {[1, 5]: 'a', 5: 23} invalid but valid_dict = {(1, 5): 'a', 5: [23, 6]} valid in python?

Tags: python, list

```
# this doesn't work
invalid_dict = {[1, 5]: 'a', 5: 23}

# but this does
valid_dict = {(1, 5): 'a', 5: [23, 6]}
print(valid_dict)
```

I want to know what's the issue with invalid_dict that it doesn't work.
I understand that a hash value is computed for each item in a dictionary for storing the key-value pair at that location in the memory. But it seems strange to me that hash value for the the tuple (1,5) can be computed but not for the list [1,5].

Comment: Because you're not allowed to use a list as a key in a dictionary.

Comment: "*dictionaries are indexed by keys, which can be any 
**immutable** type*" from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 0):

Because tuple (1, 5) is passed by value and list [1,5] by reference.

There is no technical reasons for Python no to index by list but such strict behavior prevents lots of different confusions and post probably is faster.

Imagine this code:

```
k = [1,5]
d = {k: 7}
print d[k] # returns 7
k.append(6)
print d[k] # what should be returned here? 7 because we put by k or nothing because we put by [1,5] and now it’s [1,5,6]?
```

Developers should not be confused by such cases.

It’s not the case with tuple because it’s passed as a copy and you have no access to modify copy that was passed to func or indexer statement.